# Flask gives 404 when trying to render a template

Tags: python, flask

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("home.html")
```

My folder structure looks like this

```
tree-/
   -static/
      -styles.css
   -templates/
      -home.html
   -app.py
```

I get

**Not Found**

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

On the browser and

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2021 09:41:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

In the debugger

Have looked at other related posts saying stuff about trailing slashes and it doesn't look like its making a difference, either I access
http://127.0.0.1:5000
or
http://127.0.0.1:5000/

I run my application using

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I get

```py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World"
```

Comment: Where is the file containing your flask app in your directory structure?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it, edited!

Comment: if it couldn't find template then it should ratehr show error `TemplateNotFound`. Maybe it is some different problem. Do you have this problem when you use `return "Hello World"`?

Comment: @furas Yes, 
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World"
It  gives the same error both in debugger and in the web page

Comment: @123wa could you share how do you run your app? maybe you configured a different port?

Comment: I can get this error only if I remove `@app.route('/')` - so maybe you runs wrong file - maybe you edit one file but you run different file

Comment: btw: did you restart flask after changing code?

Comment: @Gabip Check edits

Comment: And @furas, yes

Comment: if you runs `app = Flask(__name__) ; if __name__ == '__main__': app.run()` then you run it without `@app.route('/') def index(): ...` and it makes all problem. Where do you keep `@app.route('/') def index(): ...` if you don't have it in main file?

Comment: @furas This is a misunderstanding, I didn't post the full code.
Please check edits.

Comment: at this moment you shows 2 differen codes. Remove wrong code and keep only correct one.

Comment: I thing I see problem - you have to use `app.run()` at the end of file - after `@app.route('/') def index(): ...`

Comment: What do you mean "wrong code?

Comment: You were right, thank you! I will post this as a solution for other people looking over this

Comment: frankly, in every tutorial you can see `app.run()` at the end of code. I didn't expect that someone will put it in different order.

Comment: I would have never thought it would've actually mattered, Usually this order-to-execution stuff doesn't matter.
At least in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is order of code.

Line `app.run()` has to be at the end of code because it runs endless code/loop (which gets requests from clients/browsers and sends reponses) and it blocks next lines of code. All code after `app.run()` is executed after server is closed.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Move `app.run()` to the bottom.

Thanks to furas for this solution, hope this can help people looking at this thread